# Unity deserializing ".dat" file in android?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just finished building my android game and when I try to play it on android. Nothing gets spawned. I think that it has to do with my file which is responsible for holding all the locations to instantiate. Please help me fix this.

```
public class DataHolder : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static DataHolder dataholder;
    public MazeData currentmaze;

    void Awake()
    {
        if (dataholder == null)
        {
            dataholder = this;
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
        string directory = Application.dataPath + "/LevelData/"; ;
        int number =Convert.ToInt32(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name) -1;
        if (File.Exists(directory + "/Level_" + number.ToString() + "/Level_" + number.ToString() + ".dat"))
        {
            BinaryFormatter binary = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream file = File.Open(directory + "/Level_" + number.ToString() + "/Level_" + number.ToString() + ".dat", FileMode.Open);
            MazeData _level = (MazeData)binary.Deserialize(file);
            currentmaze = _level;
            file.Close();
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: well first I would print the value of number. Then I would check the name of the file that is being searched for. Then whether it is found or not. Basically, can you print inside the if statement.

Comment: @Everts code please

Comment: What? No you code please? Am I the one asking? I am just telling you to put some printings in your code so you can track what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using Application.persistentDataPath instead for your directory. I believe this is where you usually want to store your save files as `Application.dataPath` returns the file path to the apk on Android.

E.g. Change this line `string directory = Application.dataPath + "/LevelData/"; ;`

to `string directory = Application.persistentDataPath + "/LevelData/";`